# Can't create a .exe file with PyInstaller error with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

Im working with Python 3.7.3 and PyInstaller 4.0, and windows 10. My script looks like

```
import pandas as pd
print('hello')
```

But when I try to do the .exe file I have an error.

I have tried the following so far:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pandas --onefile myscript.py
```

But it doesn't work. I also update to the current development version here:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Also, I edit the .spec file and write

```
# -*- mode: python -*-block_cipher = Nonedef get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_patha = Analysis(['FIFA.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\NBenton\\PycharmProjects\\RES3D_BETA'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='FIFA',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

and then run

```
pyinstaller myscript.spec --onefile
```

I know it is a common question, but the answers in other questions doesn't work for me.

Any help? 
Thank you

After a lot of lines, the error is:

```
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py", line 29, in <module>
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 528, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 330, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

Comment: what does your `hook-pandas.py` file look like?

Comment: It will be somewhere like `\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks`

Comment: from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

# Pandas keeps Python extensions loaded with dynamic imports here.
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pandas._libs')

Comment: What warnings do you see when running pyinstaller? For example `warning Hidden import pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas not found`

Answer (score 3):

## hook-pandas.py

Adding `datas = collect_data_files('pandas')` to the `hook-pandas.py` file worked for me

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

# Pandas keeps Python extensions loaded with dynamic imports here.
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pandas._libs')
datas = collect_data_files('pandas')
```

## Anaconda prompt

I also added the hidden-import `pkg_resources.py2_warn` because that was an error I received

```
(base) C:\Users\...\test_folder>pyinstaller test.py -F --hidden-import pkg_resources.py2_warn
102 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
102 INFO: Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
106 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
116 INFO: wrote C:\Users...\test_folder\test.spec
120 INFO: UPX is not available.
125 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
```

Note: `-F` is the same as `--onefile` in `pyinstaller test.py -F --hidden-import pkg_resources.py2_warn`

## test.py

```
import pandas as pd
print('hello world')
input()
```

Comment: Hmm pandas issues again. Would you mind looking into this and seeing if our hooks need updating? If so, please submit a PR. (I'm a PyInstaller developer)

Comment: @Legorooj I will take a look when I get some time. I appreciate your work on `pyinstaller`; great package.

Answer (score 1):

pyinstaller had this issue as reported [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3422)

1. Set your hidden imports as suggested in the thread:

```
hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype',
'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime',
'pandas._libs.skiplist']
```

2. If that does not work, try installing `pandas` using `pip`.

   `pip install pandas`
   and not via `conda`

I am surprised to see the version 4.0 of Pyinstaller as it has not been released as far as I know.

Comment: I do not believe this will work as the OP indicated that all the hidden imports from `pandas._libs` are collected in the `hook-pandas.py` file:  `hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pandas._libs')`